# Start-process on exception rollback

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to deploy cubes every thing works fine, but when there are errors logging in the database is getting created in Analysis server. Is there any possibility to roll back or delete the database when there are errors

```
$script:ASDeployWizard = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe"
$arguments =  @("`"$sourceDb`"", "/s:`"$logPath`"")
Start-Process -FilePath $script:ASDeployWizard -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
```

In Start-Process if there are any errors it is logging them to the given path, but the database is getting created

Comment: Do you get errors from powershell or it contains in the database?

Comment: Errors are getting logged in to a log file, I tried with try catch but no use

Comment: I guess you could read the log file with Get-Content -Tail and if error occured and then perform a db deletion

Answer (score 0):

If you get any exceptions via powershell you could use try/catch construction.

```
try {
      Do-Stuff
      Write-Host 'Things Went OK!'
}
catch{
     Write-Host 'Things Went Wrong!'
     PerformRollback
}
```